# How to add reference to another android project in Android Studio (NOT Library project) so that we can call its methods?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse ADT, the same can be done by adding project1 in project2's build path. Then, in project2.MainActivity, we could write-

```
import project1.ExportedService;

....

switch(msg.what):
case ExportedService.PUBLIC_STATIC_FINAL_VAR:
   ...
```

How can we achieve this in Android Studio?
[ Project-1 is not a Library project. It has its own APK & can be independently installed. project1 and project2 are in same workspace.]

Comment: "In Eclipse ADT, the same can be done by adding project1 in project2's build path" -- I would not recommend that approach. I suggest that you reorganize your code to factor out the common elements into a library project that can be used by both project1 and project2.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thanks for the advice! I just read in another post that to use service from Project1's library in Project2, the <service> element should also be declared in Project2's manifest. Do we always have to declare remote service in the manifest of the project using it?

Comment: "Do we always have to declare remote service in the manifest of the project using it?" -- no, and either you misunderstood what you read, or what you read is flat-out wrong. The `<service>` element goes in the app that has the service; other apps that serve as *clients* of the service do not have the `<service>` element.